# Which of the following functions are continuous$?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

(i)$ f(x)=x^2+\frac {x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac {x^2} {({1+x^2})^2}+\cdots,x\in\mathbb R$

(ii)$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos nx}{n^{\frac 3 2}}\,,x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

(iii)$f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n\,,x\in\left[-\frac 12,\frac 1 2\right]$

MY TRY:(ii)and(iii) look like sequence of function but the question is about continuity .So I am just clueless.Thank you

Note:ans:(ii)and(iii) are continuous.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Are you trying to show that the functions are continuous? This is not clear from your post.

Comment: Have you seen **uniform** continuity for sequences or series of functions ?

Comment: Have you seen the concept of convergence radius ? One thing is certain, the third series has serious problems on this respect...

Comment: I think the second one is uniformly convergence by m test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\forall n>0  \;\;\forall x\in[0,\pi]\;\;$$

$$ |(-1)^n\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}|\leq \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

$\frac{3}{2}>1\implies $ the series of functions converges normlly and uniformly at $I=[0,\pi].$

the functions $x\mapsto (-1)^n\frac{\cos(nx)}{n\sqrt{n}}$ are continuous at $I$ thus the function sum is continuous at $I$.

for the third, by ratio test, the radius of convergence is $1$, and the function sum of a power series is $C^{\infty}$ inside $(-1,1)$.

Comment: What about 1st one?@salah fatima

Comment: @SubratKumarJena factor out by $ x^2$ and use geometric sum .

Comment: That will be $1+x^2$.right?

Comment: @SubratKumarJena For $x\neq 0$ but it gives 0$ for $x=0$ so...

Comment: Ok, I understood.you mean to say the function is not continuous at $x=0$.right?@Fatima